# Android music player with BPM detection

Tags: android, music

I'm looking for an Android music player with the ability to automatically detect and display the **BPM** (Beats Per Minute) of a playing track.

Other required features:

- At least a 3-band equalizer with presets and custom presets
- Audio effects such as stereo expansion and/or virtualization
- Album art displaying
- Basic playlist management
- Folder play
- Shuffle mode
- Audio formats: at least MP3, WAV, OGG and FLAC

Nice-to-have features (not a must-have):

- Music visualizer
- Support for different skins/themes

I'd accept recommendations for non-free apps too.

For what I've seen, I'm surprised that even the most popular and/or advanced music players lack of such feature (e.g.: [Neutron](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neutroncode.mp), [Poweramp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer.unlock), [jetAudio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jetappfactory.jetaudioplus)).
Only apps for mixing music seems to have it (I recently bought [Cross DJ Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixvibes.crossdjapp)), but obviously the user experience is quite different from a typical music player.